# Coordinates of a tesseract based on a demitesseract

Tags: geometry, polytopes

Suppose we had a $16$-cell whose eight vertices have the coordinates given in the [$16$-cell Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell#Coordinates):

(±1, 0, 0, 0), (0, ±1, 0, 0), (0, 0, ±1, 0), (0, 0, 0, ±1)

If we viewed this $16$-cell as one of the two demitesseracts of a certain tesseract (meaning those eight vertices are also vertices of that tesseract), what are the possible coordinates of the other eight vertices of the tesseract?

I understand from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3733211/231608) that there can be two solutions to this, and I'd like to know both solutions.

Comment: "demitesseract" $\to$ "half-tesseract"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the solutions were practically already there in the answer post I linked to. I just had to divide everything by two in order to get the following:

First solution: $(\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2})\text{ with odd number of }-\frac{1}{2}$

Second solution: $(\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2})\text{ with even number of }-\frac{1}{2}$